# Adele's pronunciation - Can't recognise some sounds in 'Rolling in the Deep'

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I've listened to *Rolling in the deep* many times.
But I still can't hear the words being pronounced, even when I know what they are.

> Think of me in the depths of your despair .

In "in the depths of your" Adele seems to be producing different sounds, or maybe different words. Is she linking the words together so I hear different words?

So what is the normal production when these words link together? Why do they sound different? What are the phonological and phonetic processes involved?

I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Go here: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/adele/rollinginthedeep.html

Comment: @Rathony Well, the OP says he can't hear the lyrics.  Perhaps if he knows what they are, it will clear up the confusion.  If you know that Jimi Hendrix is singing  "'Scuse me, while I kiss the sky", you'll stop thinking it's  "'Scuse me, while I kiss this guy"

Comment: @Rathony yes, I am confused the pronunciation when she sings those words

Comment: @Rathony ,it's ok.thanks for your suggestion. i really can't hear she pronounces "your". I ' d give it up ......

Comment: @deadrat If you want to see why it's difficult, see my answer! :)

Comment: Gee our old LaSalle ran great!

Comment: As interesting as this question is, it's difficult to impossible to answer because not only are there possibly lots of phonetic rules involved feeding one into another, but also in singing there's almost no accounting for the slurring and eliding and unnatural fits to meter etc. all for the purposes of style that any particular singer might arbitrarily make. That's why this question is off-topic

Comment: Which is to say I can't unhear Taylor Swift sing ['all the lonely Starbuck's lovers'](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=16169).

Answer (score 6):

There are several interesting phonological and phonetic aspects of Adele's pronunciation of this line:

> Think of me in the depths of your despair

Of course, the pronunciation of a sentence will never be the same twice. [Here is the version I'm working from. It's from Youtube. This lyric begins at 1.26](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYEDA3JcQqw&t=86).

Two of the things that make Adele's singing interesting to listen to are that a) she uses a lot of genuine features of very modern regional London English pronunciation  in her songs and doesn't usually convert  to RP or  an affected American accent, and b) she uses a lot of genuine features of connected speech, including weak forms, even though she is singing.

This means that you will hear many beautiful instances of glottal stops in between vowels, vocalised /l/s at the end of syllables and the occasional use of th-fronting amongst many other features.

So, if you're used to American English or other rhotic forms of English, one of the first things you will notice is that there are no /r/s pronounced at the end of the words *your* or *despair*. This is because South Eastern varieties of British English only pronounce /r/ when it occurs before a vowel.

You will also notice that the word *of* is pronounced with the same vowel that we find at the beginning and end of the word *America*, namely a schwa /ə/. This is the way this word always sounds when it isn't stressed or doesn't occur at the end of a sentence. It does not have the same vowel we hear in the word *lot*.

So far all of this is quite normal stuff. But there are three interesting aspects to the pronunciation of this sentence here. The first is an example of perseverative assimilation. I'll explain below:

The digraph "th" can represent the sound /θ/ which we find in the word *think* or  *theta*. In grammatical words like *this, that, then, these, those* and so forth, however, it usually represents the sound /ð/ that we find in the word *the*. Now, very often in English when we get a word ending in /n/ followed by a word beginning with /ð/, both the /n/ and the /ð/ sounds change and become similar to each other. Consider:

- I**n** **th**e end

Firstly the /n/ changes so that it moves from its normal position. We now make it on the back of our top teeth. Secondly, the /ð/ changes so that it becomes a nasal sound. In other words it also becomes an /n/ made on the back of our top teeth. So instead of saying:

- ɪn ði end

We often say:

- ɪn ni end

Remember though that both of those /n/ sounds will be made on the back of the top teeth. This is exactly what happens when Adele sings this lyric. She pronounces it like this:

- Think of me, in ne ...

The next thing you'll notice is that in the word *depths* we have a lovely example of *th* cluster simplification. This time it's the *th* we find in *think* not the one we find in *those*. The symbol we use to represent it is: /θ/. There is a phonological rule in English that when a word internal /θ/ sound is surrounded on either side by consonants, the /θ/ may be dropped (the technical word is *elided*). So for example, the word *fifths*, /fɪfθs/, is often pronounced "fifs", /fɪfs/. This is what we find in Adele's pronunciation of *depths*, which she pronounces perfectly correctly as /deps/.

The last thing is that Adele's vowel in the word *your* is a bit unusual. This might be an affectation from singing, or it might be part of her accent. Instead of pronouncing *your* with the  vowel /ɔ:/ she seems to be using a glide, a diphthong, which we might represent as /ɔʊ/.

We might expect someone singing to pronounce this line like this:

- θɪŋk ɒv mi ɪn ði depθs ɒv jɔ: dɪspeə

However, Adele actually sings:

- θɪŋk əv mi ɪn nə deps əv jɔʊ dɪspeə

Comment: An excellent answer, but I'm afraid my auditory cortex supplies the /*θ*/ in *depths* and the /*ð*/ in *in the*, and it can't catch the glide in *your*.  I can understand the processes if I repeat the speech in an exaggerated fashion, but it's almost impossible for me to hear in the song.  My comment was directed to the OP's possibly hearing "different words", but he did ask for "phonological" explanations.  I hope he didn't think I was being dismissive, which would be understandable.  As always, I can't resist:  *your used to* -> *you're used to*.

Comment: @deadrat Aaargh. Why do I keep on doing that? Thanks!

Comment: @Araucaria thanks for your explanation.  Really thank so much :)

Comment: Great answer! I wonder why people would close this question; just because it is worded in a somewhat broad manner, that doesn't mean it cannot be given a comprehensive and useful answer. I suppose this happens because it only takes five people to close a question, and before it is closed noöne can realistically do anything to prevent this.

Comment: Araucaria, most modern pop music is pronounced non-rhotic, whether from an RP or GenAmE speaker. In fact one of the few genres to have word-final r's pronounced in music is bluegrass/country-western, one of its distinct characteristics.

Comment: @mitch Weird.  loads of British singers with non-rhotic accents become rhotic when they sing!

Comment: @Mitch I've been doing some exploring on YTube. Have you got any examples (from singers who normally speak with a rhotic accent)?

Comment: @Araucaria It takes a lot of work to prove a universal (and should be easy to disprove). We should do a study. In the meantime, in my copious spare time (listening to the radio) I can only say with pure anecdotal  authority that I feel like I noticed one time that maybe this was so (karaoke?). I'm not trying to turn the tables on you, but since you just looked at youtube, do you have examples at hand where songs are rhotic?

Comment: @Mitch Well, you know what it's like. You know thousands of American pop groups and then when you try and think of one ... So the ones I listened to were: The Killers, the Beach Boys, the Carpenters. Then I was in psychological and existential pain and I gave up.

Comment: @Mitch But today I was listening to Bruce Springsteen and he did seem to be non-rhotic to me when he was singing. (was the turn-tables pun deliberate?)

Comment: @wingdf1000 My pleasure. Keep asking questions! :)